# trying to print a array of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, printing

I was asked to build a function that's receive a static two dimensional array with a lot of zeroes and turn it to an array of structs. each struct contains the value which is not zero and the index of the column.
[image: Pic for easy understanding]

Now I have built it but the problem is with the print function.

1) When I try to print twice it only prints one time and the second time list becomes NULL. Why does this occur?

```
    print(list);  
    print(list);
```

2) Why can't I print like I did in the main function?

```
printf("this is just a print |%d||%d|  ", list[0]->next->next->next->data, list[0]->col);
```

Why I don't have access to it, the program crashes...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
//#include <vld.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define C 5
#define N 4

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    int col;
    struct Node *next;
} node;

node **fun(int arr[N][C]) { 
    int i, j, k;
    node **list;
    node *temp;

    list = (node**)calloc(N, sizeof(node *));

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        list[i] = NULL;
        for (j = C - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            if (arr[i][j] != 0) {
                temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                temp->data = arr[i][j];
                temp->col = j;
                temp->next = list[i];
                list[i] = temp;
            }
    }
    return list;
}

void print(node **head) {
    int i;
    node **temp = head;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        while (temp[i]) {
            printf("|%d||%d|  ", temp[i]->data, temp[i]->col);
            temp[i] = temp[i]->next;
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

void main() {
    int arr[N][C] = { {0,0,4,0,7}, {3,0,0,0,0}, {9,1,0,6,0} , {0,0,0,0,0} };
    node **list;
    list = fun(arr);

    print(list);  ///////////
    print(list);  ///////////////

    printf("this is just a print |%d||%d|  ", list[0]->next->next->next->data, list[0]->col);
}
```

Comment: About the seccond item - you are probably accessing a null "next" at some point, making it crash... If you are on linux, try debbuging it with gdb...

Comment: `temp[i]=temp[i]->next;`  destructively changes the structure of the list.

Comment: also, apparently your nexts are pointing to itself, not to the next node... Not sure if I could understand your code, but apparently this is happening when the nodes are populated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, you are destroying your list of pointer in the process of printing them:

```
    while(temp[i])
    {   printf("|%d||%d|  ",temp[i]->data,temp[i]->col);
        temp[i]=temp[i]->next;    // <---- here
    }
```

Each `temp[i]` is the same as `head[i]`, so you modify the original list as you do this.  The `while` loop exits when this value is NULL, so the end result is that all array elements are NULL.

You need to assign this value to a temporary so you can walk the list without changing it:

```
    node *temp2 = temp[i];
    while(temp2)
    {   printf("|%d||%d|  ",temp2->data,temp2->col);
        temp2=temp2->next;
    }
```

Comment: Thank your fix works, ohhhhhh so I run with Temp[i] and make in Null... I see, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your `print` function modifies the array: it uses the array elements to iterate through the lists, and leaves them with a `NULL` value.

Here is a corrected version:

```
void print(node **head) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        node *temp;
        for (temp = head[i]; temp; temp = temp->next) {
            printf("|%d||%d|  ", temp->data, temp->col);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: @EddieKnaz: סלח,  I amended the answer for compatibility with pre-C99 compilers. You should get a more modern compiler, what environment do you use?

Comment: Oh in 2017 vs it runs, sorry but I use 2010 it;s for school we use 2010 only

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 came out 10 years after the C99 standard was adopted and still did not implement most of its improvements.  Microsoft lobbied the Committee to get its *secure* APIs in but did not care to implement most of the more useful extensions. It took another 5 years for them to finally get them in.  Here is a detailed explanation: https://herbsutter.com/2012/05/03/reader-qa-what-about-vc-and-c99/